# Each then() should return a value or throw when using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a few async methods that I need to wait for completion before I return from the request. I'm using Promises, but I keep getting the error:

```
Each then() should return a value or throw // promise/always-return
```

Why is this happpening? This is my code:

```
router.get('/account', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.user.uid
  var myProfile = {}
  var profilePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc(id)
    userRef.get()
      .then(doc => { // Error occurs on this line
        if (doc.exists) {
          var profile = doc.data()
          profile.id = doc.id
          myProfile = profile
          resolve()
        } else {
          reject(Error("Profile doesn't exist"))
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
  // More promises further on, which I wait for
})
```

Comment: you can eliminate the `new Promise` here.

Comment: you *should* eliminate the `new Promise` here.

Comment: You appear to be using ESLint (or similar). Did you refer to its documentation of this test?

Comment: @DanielA.White Why is that? I use `Promise.all(profilePromise...).then().catch()` later on

Comment: The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! If you don't call `resolve` but return a value, you will have something to `return`. The `then` method should be used for [chaining, not just subscribing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572):

```
outer.get('/account', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.user.uid
  var userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc(id)
  var profilePromise = userRef.get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      var profile = doc.data()
      profile.id = doc.id
      return profile // I assume you don't want to return undefined
//    ^^^^^^
    } else {
      throw new Error("Profile doesn't exist")
//    ^^^^^
    }
  })
  // More promises further on, which I wait for:
  // profilePromise.then(myProfile => { … });
})
```

Comment: I have multiple promises where I have to wait for all of them to complete before I move on (see my comment under my post), how do I do that without using promises?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using promises"? `profilePromise` in my code is still a promise - it just does not use the `Promise` *constructor*, it is created by the `then` call directly. You can just use `Promise.all([profilePromise, …]).then(…)` as you did before.

Comment: I see, ok I'll give it a whirl!

Answer (score 38):

Add at the end of the `then()`

```
return null
```

That's it.

[Each then() should return a value or throw Firebase cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354417/each-then-should-return-a-value-or-throw-firebase-cloud-functions#)

Answer (score 4):

In your case `firebase.db.collection('users').doc(id)` returning `promise` itself, please check firebase snippet to [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/master/firestore/main/index.js#L137-L137) for node-js.

If you have multiple promises and you need to call them one by one then use [Promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

Please check this [article](https://medium.com/@shindesan2012/callback-vs-promise-and-async-await-1e46bc1780f4) this will help you.

Use following code in your case,

```
          router.get('/account', function(req, res) {

            var id = req.user.uid;
            var myProfile = {};

            var userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc(id)

            userRef.get()
            .then(doc =>  {

                if (!doc || !doc.exists) {
                   throw new Error("Profile doesn't exist")
                }

                var profile = doc.data();
                profile.id = doc.id;
                myProfile = profile;

               return myProfile;

            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('error', error);
            })

          })
```

And use Promise.all if you have multiple promises and you want's to execute them in once.

The `Promise.all(iterable)` method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

For example:

```
  var promise1 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo1');
  });
  var promise2 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo2');
  });
  var promise3 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo3');
  });

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
  .then(result =>  console.log(result))
  //result [foo1, foo2, foo3]
```

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: how can we take values out of then?

Comment: you can create a global variable and assign the result to that variable

Comment: before variable updates next line executes !, how to prevent next line execution still global variable update? My Question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/55650858/2034750

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix this issue but still want to run your code...

```
open   : eslintrc.json file (search from project root directory)
search : 'promise/always-return'
change : Case 1: if (existing value is 2) => change to 1
         Case 2: else if(existing value is "error" => change to "warn")
```

It will make this error into warning, but be careful with it... Also use eslint plungin in your editor to remind of good practice. Otherwise you won't get any promise/always-return related warnings.

Also make sure you find the right eslintrc.json if more than 1 appears on your search

Comment: Only try this if you can't solve the issue. most of the time you can solve this by just return statement inside .then()

Answer (score 0):

`why is this happening ? Each then() should return a value or throw`  So I am adding this since the why was never explained.

For anyone else wondering the why. this is not a normal JS Error. This is a direct result of using the ES-Lint promise package:

- https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise
- https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/development/rules/always-return.js

This package has a ruleset to error when it does not find a return from a promise. This can be helpful to identify promise flow errors. You could fix this by simply adding a `return` as thats what the `linter` is triggered by or editing the es-lint rule set (not recommended). Thats why I assume it works when it is not being linted causing your confusion.

```js
 router.get('/account', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.user.uid
  var myProfile = {}
  var profilePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc(id)
    userRef.get()
      .then(doc => { // Error occurs on this line
        if (doc.exists) {
          var profile = doc.data()
          profile.id = doc.id
          myProfile = profile
          return null
        } else {
          reject(Error("Profile doesn't exist"))
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
  // More promises further on, which I wait for
})
```

Here is a list of the default rulesets used by that package. Hope it helps anyone else trying to get background on why this return was needed.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "promise/always-return": "error",
    "promise/no-return-wrap": "error",
    "promise/param-names": "error",
    "promise/catch-or-return": "error",
    "promise/no-native": "off",
    "promise/no-nesting": "warn",
    "promise/no-promise-in-callback": "warn",
    "promise/no-callback-in-promise": "warn",
    "promise/avoid-new": "warn",
    "promise/no-new-statics": "error",
    "promise/no-return-in-finally": "warn",
    "promise/valid-params": "warn"
  }
```