# Each then() should return a value or throw Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function for firebase using javascript but I am stuck, I don't know the exact meaning of error and unable to solve it..
The error states: 27:65  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
    console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);

    if (!change.after.val()) {
        return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
    }
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/ServiceProvider/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
    return deviceToken.then(result => {
        const token_id = result.val();
        const payload = {
            notification: {
              title : "New Friend Request",
              body: "You Have Received A new Friend Request",
              icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

            console.log('This was the notification Feature');

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error, but rather a linter warning. Specifically, the [`promise/always-return` one](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/always-return.md)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change this:

```
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        console.log('This was the notification Feature');

    });
```

To this:

```
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        console.log('This was the notification Feature');
        return null;   // add this line

    });
```

The `then` callback just needs to return a value.

However, eslint may then complain about nested `then()` in your code, which is also an anti-pattern.  Your code should really be structured more like this:

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/ServiceProvider/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
return deviceToken.then(result => {
    // redacted stuff...
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
}).then(() => {
    console.log('This was the notification Feature');
});
```

Note that each then chains off of each other, rather than being nested inside each other.

Comment: Hey, Thanks man I have solved the issue, but fcm deliver the message if my device is connected to internet at the very moment, If I turned on internet after 30 sec, notification is lost somewhere.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, I applaud all your contributions to Firebase. But how come there are so many places on the Firebase Cloud functions web site, where they never show this part of the code, correctly. I had even written to the Feedback link to correct the code(add extra **return** where necessary), exactly like, what you have shown here, but of no avail.

Comment: @DougStevenson why did you say "The then callback just needs to return a value" but your second example the `then` only has the log function, with no return value?

Comment: @YoApps this Google lab shows a similar example of what your asking, it's pretty good too https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-promises#catch

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

    console.log('This was the notification Feature');

  });
```

into this:

```
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response=>{
      console.log('This was the notification Feature');
      return true;
    },err=>
    {
      throw err;
    });
```

As the error says when using [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) you need to return a value.

Comment: It's not necessary to capture and re-throw the error.  A rejected promise will propagate up the promise chain all the way to Cloud Functions.

Comment: "Returning" `undefined` as the value from the `then` callback is just as fine (if you don't need another value).

Comment: Hey, Thanks man I have solved the issue, but fcm deliver the message if my device is connected to internet at the very moment, If I turned on internet after 30 sec, notification is lost somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's jslinting telling you that each `.then` must include a return value. In other words, avoid [promise anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

You might find `async` functions easier to wrap your head around. Note that you'll need to run the Node 8 runtime for async support though...

Comment: It's not the promise *constructor* antipattern that you linked though