# Each then() should return a value or throw, promise/always-return

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a simple firebase cloud function using node.js to read a collection, but when deploying it I get this error:

**Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return**

The code is the following

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let db = admin.firestore();

db.collection('collection').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    return console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

I tried to add returns but still the error occurs.

`return console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());`

`return console.log('Error getting documents', err);`

Comment: Jsut a guess but the first one `then((snapshot) => { ... })` is not returning anything. The return inside the forEach is not the part it's complaining about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Each then() should return a value or throw Firebase cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354417/each-then-should-return-a-value-or-throw-firebase-cloud-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning inside a function :) it doesn't count, you must add it here:

```
db.collection('collection').get().then((snapshot) => {
  return snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    return console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From **[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection):** (untested it myself)

```
return db.collection('collection').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    return console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  return console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```