# Query.data is not a function - Cloud funtions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code below, following the example of this link: https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/814a75ff55d5a3f951f8a7df3979636a .Only that is returning error.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.alertHelp = functions.firestore
    .document('chamados/{userId}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        try {
            const snapshot = change.after;
            const val = snapshot.data();
            const tid = val.tid;
    
            const collection = db.collection('permissons');
            const query = await collection.where('tid', '==', tid).get();
            const token = query.data().fcmToken;

            const promises = [];
            token.forEach(fcm => {
                const p = admin.firestore().doc(`{userId}/${fcm}`).get();
                promises.push(p);
            });

            const snapshots = await Promise.all(promises);

            const results = [];
            snapshots.forEach(snap => {
                const data = snap.data().fcmToken;              
                results.push(data);
            })

            console.log(results);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            
        }
     
});
```

**Error**

> query.data is not a function

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
const query = await collection.where('tid', '==', tid).get();
```

`query` is going to be a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) type object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it doesn't have a `data()` method.  That's what the error is trying to tell you.

A QuerySnapshot can contain zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects.  You have to write code to check for and iterate those results.  You can use the `forEach` method, or the `docs` property on the QuerySnapshot to do this.  You might want to review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) about that.

Comment: I changed the code according to the documentation: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query). But I am getting an deploy error. I tried to fix it with a solution here from the stackoverflow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354417/each-then-should-return-a-value-or-throw-firebase-cloud-functions). But it did not work. `Error: 18:21 error Each then () should return a value or throw promise / always-return 35:32 warning Avoid nesting promises promise / no-nesting`

Comment: If you have a new problem, post it separately.  But before you do that, do a web search for that error message. It's very common.

Comment: I already posted on another question, and it was marked as a duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565440/firestore-cloud-functions-query?noredirect=1#comment114165486_64565440). But the solution that indicated did not help me. I tried the corrections but the error remains.

Comment: I think you really should follow the advice in the duplicate.  It's the same pattern for all JavaScript.

Comment: I will try another way. Thank you.